# Can an Android Library module act as a whole application?

Tags: android, android-studio, module

My application should have 3 "sub" applications which should act independently of one another but they need to have a minor connection between them.

So my idea was to make the main app module of the project handle the login part, and show the selection menu for the sub-apps, while the sub apps would be written as separate Android Library modules.

The problem is, that i try to convert one of the sub-apps into an Android Module, but once i do it, i cannot add a dependency to it because it is not recognized as a module.

I tried creating an empty AndroidLibrary module and add an empty activity to it, and it works fine... But i cant understand where is the line that once crossed, makes the IDE think that it is no longer a module, but a full app?

Comment: do you want the other apps to be as separated apps or just an activity inside your main app?

Comment: At the moment i just think that it should call the MainActivity from the sub_app module with an intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after opening a new AndroidLibrary module and attaching from it to the main app from the beginnig when it is still empty, i found out that the problem was that in the sub_app gradle module i replaced the `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` with `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` by accident and thats what made most of the problems. Also, there were some inconsistencies in other parts of gradle which were pretty easy to fix once i made the transition slowly, one dependency at a time.